# store captured image in MySQL database with Python and OpenCV

Tags: python, mysql, image, opencv

I have a piece of code here which captures an image from my internal webcam on my laptop. With this image, i would like to directly send it to my MySQL database. here is the code.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode
from time import sleep
import serial

# Obtain connection string information from the portal
config = {
  'host':'oursystem.mysql.database.azure.com',
  'user':'user',
  'password':'pass',
  'database':'projectdb'
}

try:
   conn = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
   print("Connection established")
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
  if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
    print("Something is wrong with the user name or password")
  elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
    print("Database does not exist")
  else:
    print(err)

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists Camera (img BLOB);")
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Check if the webcam is opened correctly
if not cap.isOpened():
    raise IOError("Cannot open webcam")

frame = cap.read()[1]
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Camera (img) VALUES %s",frame)
cap.release()
```

As you guys can see, I am trying to directly send the image that is captured and stored in the variable 'frame' to my database, but it isn't working. Any ideas?

Comment: "but it isn't working. Any ideas"?? What is not working anny errors? No you need to debug..

Comment: everything else works fine and when it gets to the insert statement it gives an SQL syntax error near the %s

Comment: Yes because the MySQL syntax for INSERTS is ... `INSERT INTO [table] ([column, ....]) VALUES([values, ....])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Camera (img) VALUES(%s)",(frame,))
```

This being said, storing images in a SQL database is seldom a good idea - but if you really want to do so, at least add a primary key to your table.

EDIT : from your comments, it looks like `frame` is a `numpy.ndarray`. Your database connector does not know how to convert each and any python type to something the database will understand, so you have to manually convert your `frame` to a byte string (`bytes` in Python3, `str` in Python2).

Comment: thank you for your comment Bruno, I have tried your answer and it still throws the syntax error near the (%s). it's very odd. I was going to add a primary key after I got the image to store

Comment: Actually (assuming `frame` is a string or bytestring), it should have been `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Camera (img) VALUES(%s)",(frame,))` (corrected). But failing to pass arguments as a list or tuple should raise a TypeError, not a SQL syntax error. What is `frame` actually ?

Comment: frame is just a captured image from my camera. I could save the image as a png or jpeg and insert it that way but I need to store more than one image. as you said, running the file with the code you supplied threw a type error saying - python 'ndarray' cannot be converted to a mySQL type

Comment: "just a captured image"  is not a Python data type - looks like what you have is actually a `numpy.ndarray`, so you have to convert it to a byte string (`bytes` in   Python3, `str` in Python 2) before passing it to `cursor.execute()`

Comment: I have converted the numpy array now like you said and parsed it to the cursor.execute like so: pic = str(frame)
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Camera (img) VALUES(%s)",(pic,))   This seems to work with no errors but when i look at the database nothing is inserted for the image

Comment: You need to commit the transaction.

Comment: thank you so much. after committing the transaction it added as a blob to my image table. now i will have to try and retrieve that through java