# Python: open file and store fileobject as ..what?

Tags: python

Hi I read a file into *fileContent*

```
with open(window.filename, mode='rb') as file: # b is important -> binary
    fileContent = file.read()
```

now I want to store *fileContent* - lets say in mysql - so I can restore the file later on demand.. fileContent is now a fileobject as i unterstood, so how would I store it ? .. I would need to convert it to a string and then later i should be able to convert it back to fileobject so I could do a

```
newFile = open("savedFile.jpg", "wb")
newFile.write(fileContent)
```

?

Comment: `type(fileContent)` would probably be `bytes`, the binary equivalent to a string. it is independent of the file and can be written to a different file using the code you have.  What is the question?

Comment: `file` is a file object, `fileContent` is a bytes object (similar to a string).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert bytes to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string)

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen .. i want to store the bytes to lets say a txtfile or a entry in a mysql-db

Comment: ok but as I say, the second code block in your question contains the code to store it in another file, if you want it to be a txt file just change the extension.  And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47906415/5827215) can show you how to store it in a database, again the bytes object is what is getting stored.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found out, the byte-object needs only to be casted to a string :)

```
str(fileContent)
```